Proving gauge transformation of non-abelian field strength
For a general Yang-Mills theory, we have the field strength
$$F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu - ig [A_\mu, A_\nu]$$ I now want to prove that it transforms as $$F_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow U(x) F_{\mu\nu} U^\dagger(x)$$ under the following gauge transformation $$  A_\mu(x) \rightarrow U(x)A_\mu(x) U^\dagger(x) - \frac{i}{g}(\partial_\mu U(x))U^\dagger(x).$$
I have calculated the first term of the field strength under the gauge transformation and I obtain
\begin{align}
    \partial_\mu A'_\nu =& \partial_\mu \bigg[U(x)A_\nu(x) U^\dagger(x) - \frac{i}{g}(\partial_\nu U(x))U^\dagger(x)\bigg] \\
    =& \partial_\mu(U(x))A_\nu(x) U^\dagger(x)+ U(x)\partial_\mu(A_\nu(x)) U^\dagger(x) + U(x)A_\nu(x)\partial_\mu (U^\dagger(x)) \nonumber \\ 
    &- \frac{i}{g}\partial_\mu\bigg[(\partial_\nu U(x))U^\dagger(x)\bigg]\\
    =& ig \partial_\mu \alpha^a T^a UA_\nu U^\dagger + U (\partial_\mu A_\nu)U^\dagger -ig \partial_\mu \alpha^a  UA_\nu U^\dagger T^a  + \partial_\mu\partial_\nu \alpha^aT^a \\
    =& U (\partial_\mu A_\nu)U^\dagger + ig \partial_\mu \alpha^a\bigg[ T^a UA_\nu U^\dagger - UA_\nu U^\dagger T^a  \bigg] + \partial_\mu\partial_\nu \alpha^aT^a
\end{align}
I can kind of see that the first term is the one we want and the last term will vanish from the second term in the field strength, but I am very confused about the term with the brackets because we are `multiplying' an element of the Lie algebra with an element of the Lie group and I don't know what to do there. I think I should be using the Jacobi identity somewhere due to this question, but I can't see where to use it.
EDIT:
I found that $$\partial_\mu U = \partial_\mu \sum_n \frac{(ig \alpha^a(x)T^a)^n}{n!} =  ig \alpha^a(x)T^a \sum_n \frac{(ig \alpha^b(x)T^b)^n}{n!} = ig \alpha^a(x)T^a U,$$ but apparently this is incorrect. I can't really see why though.

I think you can brute-force it without knowledge of structure constants.  Just keep $\partial U$ as-is and don't bring down that $\alpha$.  As for the multiplication, what's wrong with multiplying NxN matrices together?  In case you haven't notice, $A$ lives in the Lie algebra but you just happily wrote down $U A U^{\dagger}$, didn't you?

$\partial_\mu U \neq i g \partial_\mu \alpha^a T^a U$. Follow what @Vokaylop said.

@Prahar wait that confused me, why isn't that true?

@Vokaylop, then I'm really confused on what to do with $\partial U_\mu$? Would you mind to sketch the idea?

You don't do anything with it. You keep it as it is. There is no need to introduce $\alpha$ into the calculation. Work exclusively with $U$.

@Geigercounter - Test it out. Expand $U$ in powers of $\alpha$. Then take a derivative and try to check if that's true or not. PS - Why do you think its true in the first place?

@Prahar I would say it is true just from the definition of the exponential as a series? I've written it out and I don't see why you can't do this?

@Geigercounter - Have you actually tried it?

@Prahar I edited my post with the confusion I had, but the accepted answer has the result!

Specifically regarding the derivative. By definition:
$$
U(x) = \exp(i \alpha_a(x) T^{a}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(i \alpha_a(x) T^a)^n}{n!} 
$$
Taking derivative yields
$$
\partial U = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{n}
\frac{1}{n!} (i \alpha_a T^a)^m \; ( i \partial \alpha_a \, T^a ) (i \alpha_a T^a)^{n-m-1}.
$$
$\alpha_a \, T^a$ and $\partial \alpha_a \, T^a$ don't necessarily commute.  You can't pull that term to the front.

Of course, this is very true and totally slipped under my radar. Thanks!!

You are making heavy weather of something easy. I'll use slightly different conventions but the result is the same.
Start by defining  the gauge-covariant derivative
$$
\nabla_\mu=\partial_\mu+A_\mu.
$$
Now  show that the commutator of two of these is equal to
$$
[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu]= F_{\mu\nu}.
$$
Now use
$$
g^{-1} (\partial_\mu+A_\mu) g = (\partial_\mu+A^g_\mu)
$$
where
$$
A^g_\mu= g^{-1}A_
\mu g+g^{-1}\partial_\mu g,
$$
and
$$
g^{-1} [\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu]g=  [g^{-1}\nabla_\mu g, g^{-1}\nabla_\nu g]
$$
to see immediately that $F\to g^{-1}Fg$.
With regard to the Maurer-Cartan form $g^{-1} dg$ note that diffferentiating the exponential is non trivial because for a  matrix $A$
$$
e^{A+ \delta A}\ne e^A e^{\delta A}= e^A(1+ \delta A+\ldots)
$$ because $A$ and $\delta A$ do not commute with each other. Instead we have the Campbell-Baker-Hausdorf formula
$$ 
e^{-A} e^{A+\delta A}= 1+ \int_0^1 e^{-tA} \delta A e^{tA} dt + O[(\delta A)^2]
$$
This is why, as @Prahar says, you should just keep the Lie-algebra element  $g^{-1}dg$ as one thing.

I would mark this as the accepted answer, but the question was more about the Lie group vs Lie algebra. The point is to not do the differentiation explicitly!

@Geigercounter No problem! I understood where you were going, but  still wanted to point you in the "right" direction. I do not need the points. I just enjoy explaining stuff that  I imagine that  I  that have understood...

Here is a derivation using explicit indices for the matrix components of elements of the Lie group and lie algebra.
I'm using $g=1$.
For a change of gauge $\varphi:\mathcal  M \to G$ the gauge field transforms according to
\begin{align}
\label{eq:classical_trans_boson}
A_\mu{}^a{}_b(x) \to A_{\mu}{}^{\tilde a}{}_{\tilde b}(x):= \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) A_\mu{}^a{}_b(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x) + \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{c}(x) \partial_\mu \varphi^{-1}{}^{c}{}_{\tilde b}(x)\,.
\end{align}
The field strength tensor is given by
\begin{align}
F_{\mu\nu}{}^{a}{}_{b} = \partial_{[\mu} A_{\nu]}{}^{a}{}_{b}+ A_{[\mu}{}^{a}{}_{c} A_{\nu]}{}^{c}{}_{b}\,.
\end{align}
(with the convention that $F = F_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu \wedge dx^{\nu}$)
Transformation of the field strength
We have
\begin{align}
F_{\mu\nu}{}^{\tilde a}{}_{\tilde b}(x) 
= \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) F_{\mu\nu}{}^{a}{}_{ b}(x)
\varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x)\,.
\end{align}

Proof:
\begin{align}
F_{\mu\nu}{}^{\tilde a}{}_{\tilde b}(x) 
&= \partial_{[\mu} A_{\nu]}{}^{\tilde a}{}_{\tilde b}(x) 
+ A_{[\mu}{}^{\tilde a}{}_{\tilde c}(x) A_{\nu]}{}^{\tilde c}{}_{\tilde b}(x)\,.
\end{align}
For the first term we have
\begin{align}
\label{eq:class_first_part}
\partial_{[\mu} A_{\nu]}{}^{\tilde a}{}_{\tilde b}(x) 
&=  \partial_{[\mu} ( \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) A_{\nu]}{}^{ a}{}_{ b}(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x))
 + \partial_{[\mu} ( \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{c}(x) [\partial_{\nu]} \varphi^{-1}{}^{c}{}_{\tilde b}(x)])
\nonumber\\
&=  (\partial_{[\mu}  \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x)) A_{\nu]}{}^{ a}{}_{ b}(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x)\nonumber\\
&+  \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) (\partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu]}{}^{ a}{}_{ b}(x)) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x)\nonumber\\
& + \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) A_{[\nu}{}^{ a}{}_{ b}(x) (\partial_{\mu]} \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x))\nonumber\\
& + \partial_{[\mu} ( \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{c}(x) [\partial_{\nu]} \varphi^{-1}{}^{c}{}_{\tilde b}(x)])\,.
\tag{1}
\end{align}
For the second term we have
\begin{align}
\label{eq:class_second_part}
A_{[\mu}{}^{\tilde a}{}_{\tilde c}(x) A_{\nu]}{}^{\tilde c}{}_{\tilde b}(x)
&= \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) A_{[\mu}{}^{a}{}_{g}(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{g}{}_{\tilde c}(x)
\varphi^{\tilde c}{}_{f}(x) A_{\nu]}{}^{f}{}_{b}(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x)\nonumber\\
&+ \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) A_{[\mu}{}^{a}{}_{g}(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{g}{}_{\tilde c}(x)
\varphi^{\tilde c}{}_{k}(x) [\partial_{\nu]} \varphi^{-1}{}^{k}{}_{\tilde b}(x)]\nonumber\\
&+ \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{d}(x) [\partial_{[\mu} \varphi^{-1}{}^{d}{}_{\tilde c}(x)]
\varphi^{\tilde c}{}_{f}(x) A_{\nu]}{}^{f}{}_{b}(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x)\nonumber\\
&+ \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{d}(x) [\partial_{[\mu} \varphi^{-1}{}^{d}{}_{\tilde c}(x)]
\varphi^{\tilde c}{}_{k}(x)[\partial_{\nu]} \varphi^{-1}{}^{k}{}_{\tilde b}(x)]\nonumber\\
%
%
&=\varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) A_{[\mu}{}^{a}{}_{g}(x) \delta^g{}_f A_{\nu]}{}^{f}{}_{b}(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x)\nonumber\\
&+ \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) A_{[\mu}{}^{a}{}_{g}(x) \delta^g{}_k [\partial_{\nu]} \varphi^{-1}{}^{k}{}_{\tilde b}(x)]\nonumber\\
&-[\partial_{[\mu} \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{d}(x)] \delta^d{}_f A_{\nu]}{}^{f}{}_{b}(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x)\nonumber\\
&-[\partial_{[\mu} \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{d}(x)]\delta^d{}_k
[\partial_{\nu]} \varphi^{-1}{}^{k}{}_{\tilde b}(x)]\nonumber\\
%
%
&=\varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) A_{[\mu}{}^{a}{}_{f}(x)  A_{\nu]}{}^{f}{}_{b}(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x)\nonumber\\
&-[\partial_{[\mu} \varphi^{-1}{}^{k}{}_{\tilde b}(x)] \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) A_{\nu]}{}^{a}{}_{k}(x) \nonumber\\
&-[\partial_{[\mu} \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{d}(x)] A_{\nu]}{}^{d}{}_{b}(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x)\nonumber\\
&-[\partial_{[\mu} \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{d}(x)]
[\partial_{\nu]} \varphi^{-1}{}^{d}{}_{\tilde b}(x)]\,.\tag{2}
\end{align}
By comparing (1) and (2), we see that all terms that depend on derivatives of $\varphi$ or $\varphi^{-1}$ cancel each other. Thus, we are left with
\begin{align}
F_{\mu\nu}{}^{\tilde a}{}_{\tilde b}(x) 
&=   \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) (\partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu]}{}^{ a}{}_{ b}(x)) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x)
+ \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) A_{[\mu}{}^{a}{}_{f}(x)  A_{\nu]}{}^{f}{}_{b}(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x)\nonumber\\
&=   \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a}(x) F_{\mu\nu}{}^{ a}{}_{ b}(x) \varphi^{-1}{}^{b}{}_{\tilde b}(x)
\,.
\end{align}
Remark:
If your gauge group can be represented as a subgroup $G \subset \operatorname{U}(n)$ of the unitary group, then of course $\varphi^{-1} = \varphi^\dagger$. In the case, your formula follows.
